# Insert data in opencart 2.1.0.1 order with javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, opencart

I have created a custom payment method in my `opencart`, and I edited the `.tpl` file with adding a table with radio buttons.

**This is an example:**

```
<tr>
              <td><div class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="tbi6"  />6 месеца x <?php echo round($order_info['total']/5.50, 2).'лв.';?></label>
                </div></td>
              <td><div class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="uni6"  />6 месеца x <?php echo round($order_info['total']*(18.57/100), 2).'лв.';?></label>
                </div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><div class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="tbi9"  />9 месеца x <?php echo round($order_info['total']/7.92, 2).'лв.';?></label>
                </div></td>
              <td><div class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="uni9"  />9 месеца x <?php echo round($order_info['total']*(12.97/100), 2).'лв.';?></label>
                </div></td>
            </tr>
```

I want to add the data from the radio button selected from the client in his order, so the admin will be able to see it after the checkout process. It works for me if I can simply add this info in the comment section. How can I achieve it?
This is my payment_method.php file :

```
class ControllerCheckoutPaymentMethod extends Controller {
public function index() {
    $this->load->language('checkout/checkout');
    if (isset($this->session->data['payment_address'])) {
        // Totals
        $total_data = array();
        $total = 0;
        $taxes = $this->cart->getTaxes();

        $this->load->model('extension/extension');

        $sort_order = array();

        $results = $this->model_extension_extension->getExtensions('total');

        foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
            $sort_order[$key] = $this->config->get($value['code'] . '_sort_order');
        }

        array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $results);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) {
                $this->load->model('total/' . $result['code']);

                $this->{'model_total_' . $result['code']}->getTotal($total_data, $total, $taxes);
            }
        }

        // Payment Methods
        $method_data = array();

        $this->load->model('extension/extension');

        $results = $this->model_extension_extension->getExtensions('payment');

        $recurring = $this->cart->hasRecurringProducts();

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) {
                $this->load->model('payment/' . $result['code']);

                $method = $this->{'model_payment_' . $result['code']}->getMethod($this->session->data['payment_address'], $total);

                if ($method) {
                    if ($recurring) {
                        if (method_exists($this->{'model_payment_' . $result['code']}, 'recurringPayments') && $this->{'model_payment_' . $result['code']}->recurringPayments()) {
                            $method_data[$result['code']] = $method;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $method_data[$result['code']] = $method;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $sort_order = array();

        foreach ($method_data as $key => $value) {
            $sort_order[$key] = $value['sort_order'];
        }

        array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $method_data);

        $this->session->data['payment_methods'] = $method_data;
    }

    $data['text_payment_method'] = $this->language->get('text_payment_method');
    $data['text_comments'] = $this->language->get('text_comments');
    $data['text_loading'] = $this->language->get('text_loading');

    $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

    if (empty($this->session->data['payment_methods'])) {
        $data['error_warning'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_no_payment'), $this->url->link('information/contact'));
    } else {
        $data['error_warning'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->session->data['payment_methods'])) {
        $data['payment_methods'] = $this->session->data['payment_methods'];
    } else {
        $data['payment_methods'] = array();
    }

    if (isset($this->session->data['payment_method']['code'])) {
        $data['code'] = $this->session->data['payment_method']['code'];
    } else {
        $data['code'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->session->data['comment'])) {
        $data['comment'] = $this->session->data['comment'];
    } else {
        $data['comment'] = '';
    }

    $data['scripts'] = $this->document->getScripts();

    if ($this->config->get('config_checkout_id')) {
        $this->load->model('catalog/information');

        $information_info = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformation($this->config->get('config_checkout_id'));

        if ($information_info) {
            $data['text_agree'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_agree'), $this->url->link('information/information/agree', 'information_id=' . $this->config->get('config_checkout_id'), 'SSL'), $information_info['title'], $information_info['title']);
        } else {
            $data['text_agree'] = '';
        }
    } else {
        $data['text_agree'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->session->data['agree'])) {
        $data['agree'] = $this->session->data['agree'];
    } else {
        $data['agree'] = '';
    }

    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/checkout/payment_method.tpl')) {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/checkout/payment_method.tpl', $data));
    } else {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/checkout/payment_method.tpl', $data));
    }
}

public function save() {
    $this->load->language('checkout/checkout');



    $json = array();

    if(isset($this->request->post['months'])){
    $this->session->data['months'] = $this->request->post['months'];
    }

    // Validate if payment address has been set.
    if (!isset($this->session->data['payment_address'])) {
        $json['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL');
    }

    // Validate cart has products and has stock.
    if ((!$this->cart->hasProducts() && empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) || (!$this->cart->hasStock() && !$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout'))) {
        $json['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
    }

    // Validate minimum quantity requirements.
    $products = $this->cart->getProducts();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $product_total = 0;

        foreach ($products as $product_2) {
            if ($product_2['product_id'] == $product['product_id']) {
                $product_total += $product_2['quantity'];
            }
        }

        if ($product['minimum'] > $product_total) {
            $json['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');

            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isset($this->request->post['payment_method'])) {
        $json['error']['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_payment');
    } elseif (!isset($this->session->data['payment_methods'][$this->request->post['payment_method']])) {
        $json['error']['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_payment');
    }

    if ($this->config->get('config_checkout_id')) {
        $this->load->model('catalog/information');

        $information_info = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformation($this->config->get('config_checkout_id'));

        if ($information_info && !isset($this->request->post['agree'])) {
            $json['error']['warning'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_agree'), $information_info['title']);
        }
    }

    $extra = '';

    if(isset($this->session->data['months'])){
        $extra = $this->session->data['months'];
    }

    if (!$json) {
        $this->session->data['payment_method'] = $this->session->data['payment_methods'][$this->request->post['payment_method']];

        $this->session->data['comment'] = $extra . " " .strip_tags($this->request->post['comment']);
    }

    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
```

And this is the .tpl file, from my custom payment method(leasing plans) where ive inserted the radio buttons with needed data:

```js
$('#button-confirm').on('click', function() {
 $.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'index.php?route=payment/leasing_plans/confirm',
  cache: false,
  beforeSend: function() {
   $('#button-confirm').button('loading');
  },
  complete: function() {
   $('#button-confirm').button('reset');
  },
  success: function() {
   location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
  }
 });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.leasecond").hide();
    $("input[name$='months']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.leasecond").hide();
        $("#" + test).show();
    // Place the text from the div in the textarea element. Постави ID на textarea !!!
     // $("#text_leasing").text($("#" + test).text());
    });
});

$('#input-payment-egn').keyup(function(e){
  if($(this).val().length === 10)
    e.preventDefault();
}).focusout(function(){
  if($(this).val().length === 10){
    $('#wrong-egn').slideUp();
  } else {
    $('#wrong-egn').slideDown();
  }
});
```

```css
    td{
      text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
         }
   /*tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}*/
    tr:hover {background-color: #f5f5f5}
 
 .leasecond{
 display: none;
 }
```

```html
<h2><?php echo $text_instruction; ?></h2>
<p><b><?php echo $text_description; ?></b></p>
<div class="well well-sm">

    <div class="well" style="display: table; cursor: pointer;">
            <table align="left" cellspacing="1" style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%;">
              <caption style="text-align: left;" id="tablica">
              <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-calendar fa-3x"></i>&nbsp;Избери схема на изплащане:
              </caption>
              <thead id="tablica1">
                <tr>
                  <td ><img alt="" height="40" src="http://dev.mupcku.com/image/TBI-logo-b.png" /></td>
                  <td><img alt="" height="40" src="http://dev.mupcku.com/image/unicredit-logo-b.png" /></td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tablica2">
                <tr>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="tbi3"  />3 месеца x <?php echo round($order_info['total']/2.87, 2).'лв.';?></label>
     </div></td>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="uni3"  />3 месеца x <?php echo round($order_info['total']*(35.02/100), 2).'лв.';?></label>
     </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="tbi6"  />6 месеца x <?php echo round($order_info['total']/5.50, 2).'лв.';?></label>
     </div></td>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="uni6"  />6 месеца x <?php echo round($order_info['total']*(18.16/100), 2).'лв.';?></label>
     </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="tbi9"  />9 месеца x <?php echo round($order_info['total']/7.92, 2).'лв.';?></label>
     </div></td>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="uni9"  />9 месеца x <?php echo round($order_info['total']*(12.55/100), 2).'лв.';?></label>
     </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="tbi12"  />12 месеца x <?php echo round($order_info['total']/10.16, 2).'лв.';?></label>
     </div></td>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="uni12" />12 месеца x <?php echo round($order_info['total']*(9.75/100), 2).'лв.';?></label>
     </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="tbi15"  />15 месеца x <?php echo round($order_info['total']/12.24, 2).'лв.';?></label>
     </div></td>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="uni15"  />15 месеца x <?php echo round($order_info['total']*(8.08/100), 2).'лв.';?></label>
     </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="tbi18"  />18 месеца x <?php echo round($order_info['total']/14.17, 2).'лв.';?></label>
     </div></td>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="uni18"  />18 месеца x <?php echo round($order_info['total']*(6.97/100), 2).'лв.';?></label>
     </div></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>

<div id="tbi3" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с TBI, вноски 3 х <?php echo $tbi3=round($order_info['total']/2.87, 2).'лв.';?> обща дължима сума: <?php echo ($tbi3*3).'лв.';?> ГПР: 30.36% <br>
 <p>Прочетох и разбрах записаното в документа на Ти Би Ай Кредит EАД - <a href="http://dev.mupcku.com/leasing/tbi.pdf" target="_blank">Съгласие за обработка на личните данни</a>. Потвърждавам, че съм съгласен личните ми данни да бъдат обработвани от Ти Би Ай Кредит EАД, по описания в документа начин и за целите посочени в него.</p>
</div> 
<div id="uni3" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с UNI Credit, вноски 3 x <?php echo $uni3=round($order_info['total']*(35.41/100), 2).'лв.';?> обща дължима сума: <?php echo ($uni3*3).'лв.';?> ГПР: 30.36% <br>
 <p>Правилата за ползване на Уникредит Кънсюмър Файненсинг ЕАД са - <a href="http://dev.mupcku.com/leasing/unicredit.pdf" target="_blank">Съгласие за обработка на личните данни</a>. Потвърждавам, че съм съгласен личните ми данни да бъдат обработвани от Уникредит Кънсюмър Файненсинг ЕАД, по описания в документа начин и за целите посочени в него.</p>
</div> 

<div id="tbi6" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с TBI, вноски 6 х <?php echo $tbi6=round($order_info['total']/5.50, 2).'лв.';?> обща дължима сума: <?php echo ($tbi6*6).'лв.';?> ГПР: 34.49% <br>
 <p>Прочетох и разбрах записаното в документа на Ти Би Ай Кредит EАД - <a href="http://dev.mupcku.com/leasing/tbi.pdf" target="_blank">Съгласие за обработка на личните данни</a>. Потвърждавам, че съм съгласен личните ми данни да бъдат обработвани от Ти Би Ай Кредит EАД, по описания в документа начин и за целите посочени в него.</p>
</div> 
<div id="uni6" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с UNI Credit, вноски 6 x <?php echo $uni6=round($order_info['total']*(18.57/100), 2).'лв.';?> обща дължима сума: <?php echo ($uni6*6).'лв.';?> ГПР: 34.49%  <br>
 <p>Правилата за ползване на Уникредит Кънсюмър Файненсинг ЕАД са - <a href="http://dev.mupcku.com/leasing/unicredit.pdf" target="_blank">Съгласие за обработка на личните данни</a>. Потвърждавам, че съм съгласен личните ми данни да бъдат обработвани от Уникредит Кънсюмър Файненсинг ЕАД, по описания в документа начин и за целите посочени в него.</p>
</div> 


<div id="tbi9" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с TBI, вноски 9 х <?php echo $tbi9=round($order_info['total']/7.92, 2).'лв.';?> обща дължима сума: <?php echo ($tbi9*9).'лв.';?> ГПР: 36.23% <br>
 <p>Прочетох и разбрах записаното в документа на Ти Би Ай Кредит EАД - <a href="http://dev.mupcku.com/leasing/tbi.pdf" target="_blank">Съгласие за обработка на личните данни</a>. Потвърждавам, че съм съгласен личните ми данни да бъдат обработвани от Ти Би Ай Кредит EАД, по описания в документа начин и за целите посочени в него.</p>
</div> 
<div id="uni9" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с UNI Credit, вноски 9 x <?php echo $uni9=round($order_info['total']*(12.97/100), 2).'лв.';?> обща дължима сума: <?php echo ($uni9*9).'лв.';?> ГПР: 36.23% <br>
 <p>Правилата за ползване на Уникредит Кънсюмър Файненсинг ЕАД са - <a href="http://dev.mupcku.com/leasing/unicredit.pdf" target="_blank">Съгласие за обработка на личните данни</a>. Потвърждавам, че съм съгласен личните ми данни да бъдат обработвани от Уникредит Кънсюмър Файненсинг ЕАД, по описания в документа начин и за целите посочени в него.</p>
</div> 


<div id="tbi12" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с TBI, вноски 12 х <?php echo $tbi12=round($order_info['total']/10.16, 2).'лв.';?> обща дължима сума: <?php echo ($tbi12*12).'лв.';?> ГПР: 23.69% <br>
 <p>Прочетох и разбрах записаното в документа на Ти Би Ай Кредит EАД - <a href="http://dev.mupcku.com/leasing/tbi.pdf" target="_blank">Съгласие за обработка на личните данни</a>. Потвърждавам, че съм съгласен личните ми данни да бъдат обработвани от Ти Би Ай Кредит EАД, по описания в документа начин и за целите посочени в него.</p>
</div> 
<div id="uni12" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с UNI Credit, вноски 12 x <?php echo $uni12=round($order_info['total']*(10.19/100), 2).'лв.';?> обща дължима сума: <?php echo ($uni12*12).'лв.';?> ГПР: 23.69%  <br>
 <p>Правилата за ползване на Уникредит Кънсюмър Файненсинг ЕАД са - <a href="http://dev.mupcku.com/leasing/unicredit.pdf" target="_blank">Съгласие за обработка на личните данни</a>. Потвърждавам, че съм съгласен личните ми данни да бъдат обработвани от Уникредит Кънсюмър Файненсинг ЕАД, по описания в документа начин и за целите посочени в него.</p>
</div> 


<div id="tbi15" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с TBI, вноски 15 х <?php echo $tbi15=round($order_info['total']/12.24, 2).'лв.';?> обща дължима сума: <?php echo ($tbi15*15).'лв.';?> ГПР: 23.89%  <br>
 <p>Прочетох и разбрах записаното в документа на Ти Би Ай Кредит EАД - <a href="http://dev.mupcku.com/leasing/tbi.pdf" target="_blank">Съгласие за обработка на личните данни</a>. Потвърждавам, че съм съгласен личните ми данни да бъдат обработвани от Ти Би Ай Кредит EАД, по описания в документа начин и за целите посочени в него.</p>
</div> 
<div id="uni15" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с UNI Credit, вноски 15 x <?php echo $uni15=round($order_info['total']*(8.53/100), 2).'лв.';?> обща дължима сума: <?php echo ($uni15*15).'лв.';?> ГПР: 23.89%  <br>
 <p>Правилата за ползване на Уникредит Кънсюмър Файненсинг ЕАД са - <a href="http://dev.mupcku.com/leasing/unicredit.pdf" target="_blank">Съгласие за обработка на личните данни</a>. Потвърждавам, че съм съгласен личните ми данни да бъдат обработвани от Уникредит Кънсюмър Файненсинг ЕАД, по описания в документа начин и за целите посочени в него.</p>
</div> 


<div id="tbi18" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с TBI, вноски 18 х <?php echo $tbi18=round($order_info['total']/14.17, 2).'лв.';?> обща дължима сума: <?php echo ($tbi18*18).'лв.';?> ГПР: 23.93% <br>
 <p>Прочетох и разбрах записаното в документа на Ти Би Ай Кредит EАД - <a href="http://dev.mupcku.com/leasing/tbi.pdf" target="_blank">Съгласие за обработка на личните данни</a>. Потвърждавам, че съм съгласен личните ми данни да бъдат обработвани от Ти Би Ай Кредит EАД, по описания в документа начин и за целите посочени в него.</p>
</div> 
<div id="uni18" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с UNI Credit, вноски 18 x <?php echo $uni18=round($order_info['total']*(7.44/100), 2).'лв.';?> обща дължима сума: <?php echo ($uni18*18).'лв.';?> ГПР: 23.93% <br>
 <p>Правилата за ползване на Уникредит Кънсюмър Файненсинг ЕАД са - <a href="http://dev.mupcku.com/leasing/unicredit.pdf" target="_blank">Съгласие за обработка на личните данни</a>. Потвърждавам, че съм съгласен личните ми данни да бъдат обработвани от Уникредит Кънсюмър Файненсинг ЕАД, по описания в документа начин и за целите посочени в него.</p>
</div> 


<form id="leasingform">
<div class="form-group required" style="padding-top: 15px;">
    <label class="control-label" for="input-payment-egn"><?php echo $text_egn; ?></label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="10" name="egn" value="" placeholder="Въведете вашето ЕГН" id="input-payment-egn"
                   class="form-control"/>
</div>
<div class="text-danger" id="wrong-egn" style="display: none;">Въведете валидно ЕГН !</div>
</form>

</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="pull-right">
    <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_confirm; ?>" id="button-confirm" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, where will these options be on the checkout page?

Comment: This is payment method. When user select it, tha table is showing (on payment description section) there are my radio buttons :)

Comment: I had a task that required a similar modification to the Shipping Module, my first step was to choose an existing option and see how to edit that. Are you a developer? Do you understand PHP & MVC?

Comment: I understand php and MVC but i cannot say that im a developer...give a try if you think that you have any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this site is not intended to provide you with the code to achieve a task but rather to assist with an existing problem or give guidance on how to do something. I would suggest you review how one of the existing payment modules work e.g. Bank Transfer and see how you can modify it. I can point you in the right direction if that's what you want

Comment: I followed this steps to make my custom payment method, im just confused on how i wil send the data from my radio button form to order hstory...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the script on the Checkout page that watches for the Payment Method's `click` event:

```
$(document).delegate('#button-payment-method', 'click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_method/save',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#collapse-payment-method input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #collapse-payment-method input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #collapse-payment-method textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#button-payment-method').button('loading');
        },
```

You can see that it's sending the "checked" input in that div to the route in the Ajax call (see the url). So using OpenCart's MVC implementation, you can look for the controller file here: `catalog\controller\checkout\payment_method.php` then look in that file for the `save` public function. That's where you'll receive the selected data.

To handle the second part of your query, how to show this on the backend, when I had a similar issue, I added my input value to the user's comments. In order to do that, I added the input data to the Session variable in the controller file (mentioned above) then accessed that value AFTER the user's final "Confirm" click so that the comment wasn't immediately visible to the user.

Adding the value to the session:

```
if(isset($this->request->post['months'])){
    $this->session->data['months'] = $this->request->post['months'];
}
```

Now that value can be accessed with this `$this->session->data['months']` and you can add it to the comments by editing the `save` function:

```
$extra = '';

if(isset($this->session->data['months'])){
    $extra = $this->session->data['months'];
}

if (!$json) {
    $this->session->data['payment_method'] = $this->session->data['payment_methods'][$this->request->post['payment_method']];

    $this->session->data['comment'] = $extra . " " .strip_tags($this->request->post['comment']);
}
```

I used `$extra` as the placeholder for the new data and then added it to the User's comment, only if there was a value stored in the `session`

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the perfect answer! I understand the idea, and it fits exactle my needs! I just didnt get where i must add the value to the session if(isset($this->request->post['months'])){
    $this->session->data['months'] = $this->request->post['months'];
} ?

Comment: You're welcome, you can add the first bit of code (`if(isset($this->request->post['months'])){`) towards the top of the `catalog\controller\checkout\payment_method.php` `save` function (line 132 on my side), you should have it below `public function save() {` the second piece of code can be put just before this line: `$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: Yes, i understood. Unfortunately i have tryed everything, but it still doesnt put the data from radio buttons in the comment of the order....

Comment: Why don't you add your `catalog\controller\checkout\payment_method.php` code to your question so I can review it and see if there is an issue?

Comment: I did it now :) This is the edited file, with your proposal

Comment: Which TPL file did you edit when you added your radio buttons? Can you also include that in the question?

Comment: I edited my custom payment method .tpl file, there are the radio buttons, you can see it here dev.mupcku.com i will now upload this file also to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153133/discussion-between---and-daniel).

Comment: Its just not working...if anybody else has any idea, feel free to contribute it!